# 3-level cascading dropdown list - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to create a 3-level cascading dropdown list in asp.net MVC 4 using jquery. Selecting an item in the first dropdown populates the second dropdown but the new value in the second dropdown has no effect on the third. Does anybody know how to fix this? Your help would be much appreciated!

I have tested both of the functions individually and they work fine, just not together.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getStateNames(BN) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("StateNames", "DropDownlist")",
        data: {CountryName: CN},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        error: function() {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var items = "";
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
            });

            $("#State").html(items);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Country").change(function () {
        var CN = $("#Country").val();

        getStateNames(CN);
    });
});

function getCityNames(SN) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("CityNames", "DropDownlist")",
        data: { StateName: SN },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = "";
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
            });

            $("#CityName").html(items);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#StateName").change(function () {
        var SN = $("#StateName").val();

        getCityNames(SN);
    });
});
```